# How to use Globals() to call static & instance methods in Python

Tags: python, global

How to use Globals() to call static & instance methods in Python ?

```
import sys
import json
import pprint

def Func102(arg0, arg1):
  sys.stdout.write("Func102 ARG1 :" + arg0 + ": ARG1 :"+ arg1 + ":\n");

globals()['Func102']("Hey Dude", "Wassup");


class Glob101:
  @staticmethod
  def Func101(arg0, arg1):
    sys.stdout.write("Func101 ARG1 :" + arg0 + ": ARG1 :"+ arg1 + ":\n");

print("\n\n\n");
globDict = str(globals());
print(json.dumps(globDict, indent=4, sort_keys=True));
print("\n\n\n");

globClass =  globals.get('Glob101');
globClass.Func101("THIS IS NOT WORKING", "!!!");                                                                                                                                


globals()['Glob101.Func101']("THIS IS NOT WORKING EITHER", "!!!");
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: I'm parsing some json and need to do some validations on those. So to validate each section of the json, i am calling separate functions which are in a different class. So that is why.

Comment: @ManikandarajS that doesn't make any sense... why don't you just call the function? Why are you using `staticmethod` anyway? There is almost never really a good reason to use them in Python, and as far as I've been able to figure, they were only added because lots of people from Java feel this strange need to put everything in a class definition... Also, **what do you mean "THIS ISN'T WORKING"** What isn't working, and **how**?

Comment: Because I'm pretty sure `globClass =  globals.get('Glob101')` should be `globClass = globals().get('Glob101')` But again, *why you are using `globals`* is totally unclear, and doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, for goodness sake, man, try to stick to Python style. `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`, no unecessary `;` to terminate lines, use `print` instead of `sys.stdout.write`... use `UpperCase` only for `ClassNames` it all makes your code very confusing to anyone use to Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because i have a Big JSON file and for each Dictionary or List in the JSON, i will call a function with the same name as the Dict or List Object. There are around 30 such DICT/Lists, if i have to call them like, Glob101.Func101, Glob101.Func102, ... Glob101.Func130, i am simply adding more lines of code for no reason at all. So i was looking for a way to call function using string with function names and i found the answer. Thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: @ManikandarajS I would personally avoid that design, but if you *really want* to, I would have suggested something like `getattr(Glob101, f"Glob{i}")(arg1, arg2)` in a loop where `i` will be the number of the corresponding method you want to call.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. We can use getattr and globals together to call the static function in a class.

```
import sys

class Glob101:
  def Func101(arg0, arg1):
    sys.stdout.write("Func101 ARG1 :" + arg0 + ": ARG1 :"+ arg1 + ":\n");

getattr(globals()['Glob101'], 'Func101')('This Should Work', 'I believe !!!');
```

Comment: **You don't need `globals()` here at all**

Answer (score 0):

Just use an explicit dictionary that contains the function you need. There is *no* need for a class here.

```
def parse_something(arg0, arg1):
    ...

funcs = {"func_101": parse_something}

funcs["func_101"](1, 2)
```

There is no requirement for the dictionary keys to match the name of the functions.

Comment: I need a class, where do i Put 30+ functions then ?